# Remove html link from mysql database field with SQL

Tags: mysql

I have an old MySQL database and I need to remove different HTML links from `description` field.

So, for example after SQL execution on `description` with a following text:

```
Hello <a href="http://www.example1.com">test</a> World !
```

I need to get:

```
Hello World !
```

Please note that in my database HTML links are not the same and contain different addresses and texts.

Is it possible to do with MySQL SQL query and if so, could you please provide an example.

Comment: Is each column guaranteed to have only one anchor tag?

Comment: Right now I only seen one anchor tag in the text.. but I suppose can be columns with 2+ anchor tags..

Comment: Here's the deal: In general parsing nested HTML can't even be done with regex, you need a parser.   But if the structure is known and fixed, you could handle it with regex, or even with a clever application of MySQL's string functions.  So if you can give us a structure, maybe you will get an answer.

Comment: By the way, the reason I'm asking this now is to prevent someone from answering only to find out that there is an edge case you never told us about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a query like this. You only must change **FIELDNAME** to your fieldname and **TABLENAME** to your tablename. In your Sample there are one space behind **HELLO ** and one before ** WORLD**, so you have 2 spaces in the RESULT

```
SELECT
CONCAT(
    SUBSTR(FIELDNAME,1,
    INSTR(FIELDNAME,'<a href=')-1)
,
    SUBSTR(FIELDNAME,
    INSTR(FIELDNAME,'</a>')+4)
)
FROM YOURTABLE;
```

**sample**

```
SELECT 
CONCAT(
    SUBSTR('Hello <a href="http://www.example1.com">test</a> World !',1,
    INSTR('Hello <a href="http://www.example1.com">test</a> World !','<a href=')-1)
,
    SUBSTR('Hello <a href="http://www.example1.com">test</a> World !',
    INSTR('Hello <a href="http://www.example1.com">test</a> World !','</a>')+4)
);
```

**result**

```
Hello  World !
```